Trying to do a token swap using Jupiter with Python
I am trying to swap SOL for GME in this example but the swap does not occur?
I am following the documentation from Jupiter here: https://station.jup.ag/api-v6/post-swap
I change the swap response (not sure if sensitive info)
import json
import requests

def get_jupiter_quote(input_token, output_token, amount):
    amt_in_lamports = int(amount * 1_000_000_000)  # 1 SOL = 1 billion lamports
    url = f"https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint={input_token}&outputMint={output_token}&amount={amt_in_lamports}"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()  


def jupiter_swap(TOKEN_IN, TOKEN_OUT, AMOUNT):
    WALLET_ADDRESS = "MY_WALLET_ADDRESS_HERE"
    quote_response = get_jupiter_quote(TOKEN_IN, TOKEN_OUT, AMOUNT)
    print("quote_response", quote_response)
    input_mint = quote_response["inputMint"]
    in_amount = quote_response["inAmount"]
    output_mint = quote_response["outputMint"]
    out_amount = quote_response["outAmount"]
    other_amount_threshold = quote_response["otherAmountThreshold"]
    swap_mode = quote_response["swapMode"]
    slippage_bps = quote_response["slippageBps"]
    price_impact = quote_response["priceImpactPct"]
    route_plan = quote_response["routePlan"]

    url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap"

    payload = json.dumps({
    "userPublicKey": WALLET_ADDRESS,
    "destinationTokenAccount": WALLET_ADDRESS,
    "quoteResponse": {
        "inputMint": input_mint,
        "inAmount": in_amount,
        "outputMint": output_mint,
        "outAmount": out_amount,
        "otherAmountThreshold": other_amount_threshold,
        "swapMode": swap_mode,
        "slippageBps": slippage_bps,
        "priceImpactPct": price_impact,
        "routePlan": route_plan,
        "contextSlot": 0,
        "timeTaken": 0
        }})

        headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
         }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.text


SOLANA_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
GME_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "8wXtPeU6557ETkp9WHFY1n1EcU6NxDvbAggHGsMYiHsB"
AMOUNT = 0.0001

swap_response = jupiter_swap(SOLANA_TOKEN_ADDRESS, GME_TOKEN_ADDRESS, AMOUNT)
print("swap_response", swap_response)

# THIS IS WHAT PRINTS

quote_response {'inputMint': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'inAmount': '100000', 'outputMint': '8wXtPeU6557ETkp9WHFY1n1EcU6NxDvbAggHGsMYiHsB', 'outAmount': '2575951216', 'otherAmountThreshold': '2563071460', 'swapMode': 'ExactIn', 'slippageBps': 50, 'platformFee': None, 'priceImpactPct': '0', 'routePlan': [{'swapInfo': {'ammKey': '9ZLFTnKKccCnRynVjQ41CxGqpeSNhmiUxa2gmQNciubH', 'label': 'Raydium CLMM', 'inputMint': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'outputMint': 'GvcNXdSehfNSNyhDVDj27kc459LzFqWozt9CSJywMy6r', 'inAmount': '100000', 'outAmount': '2291514323', 'feeAmount': '840', 'feeMint': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'}, 'percent': 100}, {'swapInfo': {'ammKey': 'AUgUvsWMcRZQmhotFZKixXiTGmK2EEtXfv2maGbzjm6b', 'label': 'Whirlpool', 'inputMint': 'GvcNXdSehfNSNyhDVDj27kc459LzFqWozt9CSJywMy6r', 'outputMint': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v', 'inAmount': '2291514323', 'outAmount': '16857', 'feeAmount': '1374908', 'feeMint': 'GvcNXdSehfNSNyhDVDj27kc459LzFqWozt9CSJywMy6r'}, 'percent': 100}, {'swapInfo': {'ammKey': '2YpaFmxNJ16KPjGGHgrRpXLtMA2YPCc9aXGPzLny7R1u', 'label': 'Raydium CLMM', 'inputMint': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v', 'outputMint': '8wXtPeU6557ETkp9WHFY1n1EcU6NxDvbAggHGsMYiHsB', 'inAmount': '16857', 'outAmount': '2575951216', 'feeAmount': '143', 'feeMint': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v'}, 'percent': 100}], 'contextSlot': 266194475, 'timeTaken': 0.314244659}

swap_response {"swapTransaction":"LONG_MESSY_STRING","lastValidBlockHeight":245997969,"prioritizationFeeLamports":99999}

'''

I added the below code
`

i unfortunately can not add a comment since i need 50 reputation for that... but @Solano Manlet , which version of solders are you using, since in 0.18.1 there is no solders.message attribute...

Here's code that works. Hope it helps!
Solana address if anyone feels generous: HE2cEG5YvHQVrBM8wZNjCPphf2DVydyUuxwCwoxaauQN
import requests
import base58
import base64
import json
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction
from solders import message
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.rpc.commitment import Processed

# Constants
WALLET_ADDRESS = "YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS_PUBLIC_KEY"
INPUT_MINT = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
OUTPUT_MINT = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"
AMOUNT = 5000000
QUOTE_URL = f"https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint={INPUT_MINT}&outputMint={OUTPUT_MINT}&amount={AMOUNT}"
SWAP_URL = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap"
PRIVATE_KEY = Keypair.from_bytes(base58.b58decode("YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"))
SOLANA_RPC_URL_ENDPOINT = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

# Get quote response
quote_response = requests.get(url=QUOTE_URL).json()

# Prepare swap payload
payload = {
    "quoteResponse": quote_response,
    "userPublicKey": WALLET_ADDRESS,
    "wrapUnwrapSOL": True
}

# Get swap transaction route
swap_route = requests.post(url=SWAP_URL, json=payload).json()['swapTransaction']

# Initialize Solana client
client = Client(endpoint=SOLANA_RPC_URL_ENDPOINT)

# Decode and sign the transaction
raw_transaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_route))
signature = PRIVATE_KEY.sign_message(message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_transaction.message))
signed_txn = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_transaction.message, [signature])

# Send the signed transaction
opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, preflight_commitment=Processed)
result = client.send_raw_transaction(txn=bytes(signed_txn), opts=opts)

# Extract and print the transaction ID
transaction_id = json.loads(result.to_json())['result']
print(f"Transaction sent: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/{transaction_id}")


thank you for this awesome code. I used your code and is worked as well. But now I have the problem that the TX is in the console and also that the transaction has been encrypted. I have a loop running which executes this code for different wallets (SIgner). I have also inserted a 15 second timer so that it doesn't happen so quickly.
The transactions work sporadically, but mostly not. What could it be? Here is the code section:
 rpc_url = "MY_RPC_URL" #QUICKNODE AND ALCHEMY BOTH TRIED
client = Client(rpc_url)

for wallet in wallets:
    private_key = wallet['keyPair']
    keypair = Keypair.from_base58_string(private_key)
    public_key = keypair.pubkey()
    
    swap_amount = random.uniform(0.01, 0.05)
    jupiter_url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote"
    params = {
        "inputMint": token_from,
        "outputMint": token_to,
        "amount": int(swap_amount * 1e9), 
    }
    response = requests.get(jupiter_url, params=params)
    #response.raise_for_status()
    quote = response.json()
        #swap
    url = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap'
    payload = {
        'userPublicKey':str(public_key),
         'quoteResponse': quote,
         'computeUnitPriceMicroLamports': 20000000
       }
    responsePost = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    data = responsePost.json()
    swapTransaction=data['swapTransaction']
    print(swapTransaction)
    raw_transaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swapTransaction))
    signature = keypair.sign_message(message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_transaction.message))
    signed_txn = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_transaction.message, [signature])
    opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, preflight_commitment=Processed)
    result = client.send_raw_transaction(txn=bytes(signed_txn), opts=opts)
    transaction_id = json.loads(result.to_json())['result']
    print(f"Transaction sent: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/{transaction_id}")
    time.sleep(15)

